# bootstrap loaded and didn't work as expect in a javascript library

Tags: javascript, json, bootstrap-4, widget, embed

hello I want to make a simple js code to embed a Django template, in a result put it in another website like what Iframe do. I make the logic in a way of a js library. and I have submit styles like this

```
 createFontAwesomeCssLink() {
    // Create a link element for FontAwesome CSS
    const fontAwesomeLink = document.createElement('link');
    fontAwesomeLink.rel = 'stylesheet';
    fontAwesomeLink.href = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css';
    
    // Append the link element to the document head
    return fontAwesomeLink;
  }

  createFontAwesomeCssLink2() {
    // Create a link element for FontAwesome CSS
    const fontAwesomeLink2 = document.createElement('link');
    
    
    fontAwesomeLink2.href = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    fontAwesomeLink2.rel = 'stylesheet';
    fontAwesomeLink2.integrity='sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9';
    fontAwesomeLink2.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
    // Append the link element to the document head
    return fontAwesomeLink2;
  }
  includeBootstrapJS() {
      const bootstrapScript = document.createElement('script');
      bootstrapScript.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js';
      bootstrapScript.integrity = 'sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm';
      bootstrapScript.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
      return bootstrapScript;
  }
  createJQueryScript() {
      const jqueryScript = document.createElement('script');
      jqueryScript.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js';
      jqueryScript.integrity = 'sha256-oP6HI9z1XaZNBrJURtCoUT5SUnxFr8s3BzRl+cbzUq8=';
      jqueryScript.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
      // Return the script element
      return jqueryScript;
  }
  createChatbotScript() {
    const chatbotScript = document.createElement('script');
    chatbotScript.src = '/static/js/chatbot_widget.js';
    chatbotScript.setAttribute('apikey', this.apikey);
    chatbotScript.setAttribute('domain_name', this.domain_name);
    // Return the script element
    return chatbotScript;
  }
```

but the bootsrap loaded but didn't work here an exemple of how I set bootstrap elements

hello I want to make a simple js code to embed a Django template, in a result put it in another website like what Iframe do. I make the logic in this way

```
submitIcon.classList.add('fa-solid', 'fa-paper-plane');
```